# Would this question from the Workplace SE be on topic here?

Tags: discussion

Would [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/168201/signaling-a-security-problem-to-a-company-ive-left) from The WorkPlace SE about notification of OP's still active access to company data be on topic here? As access management and revocation of access for former employees is a common concern across companies, how to notify of improper access seems to be helpful to know about.

Answer (score 5):

No. It's not a security issue for *the asker*. It is properly asked on Workplace.